# PHP CSV import handle quotes

Tags: php, csv

I am mass uploading data through CSV that has data like this

```
  "James","+15479632","New York, USA"
```

I want to handle the quotes in it because when I delete quotes before uploading, it takes the address as two seperate values. 
`New York,USA`

i currently have this

```
$data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'")
```

in my code.

thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're telling your fgetcsv command that the encapsulation of the strings is a single quote ' when its actually a double quote " in your example csv data.

Use this `$data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",",'"')`

Answer (score 0):

Your enclosure character needs to be " not '.

```
$data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,',','"');
```